# How to remove all associated security entries when deleting object in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, acl

I'm working on a simple task manager project and I use Symfony's built-in ACL system for handling access to my domain objects(tasks). The process of granting users access to particular objects and checking if user has a right to do any action on object  is described in Symfony documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) but I can't find any information on how to detach ACL entries associated with object on deleting the object. Now when i am deleting an object (I haven't yet created a controller for this, and doing it directly in phpmyadmin) the entries in
`acl_object_identities` and `acl_entries` associated with it remain intact while obviously they should drop as well. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is facing similar troubles here is how I solved it eventually after digging into Symfony classes api reference:

```
    //...
    $em->remove($task);

    //retrieving object's Object Identity
    $strat = new ObjectIdentityRetrievalStrategy();
    $taskObjectIdentity = $strat->getObjectIdentity($task);

    $aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');
    $aclProvider->deleteAcl($taskObjectIdentity);

    $em->flush();
```